# Setup VoltDB Cluster IP

Tags: database, cluster-computing, voltdb

Trying with VoltDB cluster, created a cluster of 2 nodes with k=1

Cluster initialization was successful, both the nodes are up.

Now, how do i connect to this cluster, i could not find any documentation to setup single IP for cluster.

Will the client connect to particular node IP or cluster IP ?

I am using VoltDB community edition.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can connect to one node, or to multiple nodes. For simple usage, one node is fine. For a client application where you want lower latency and higher throughput, you should connect to all of the nodes in the cluster. See [Connecting to the VoltDB Database](https://docs.voltdb.com/UsingVoltDB/ChapAppDesign.php#DesignAppConnect) for the java client, and in particular section 6.1.2 on using the auto-connecting client which enables you to connect to only one node and the client will automatically connect to all of the other nodes.

For command-line access, see the [sqlcmd](https://docs.voltdb.com/UsingVoltDB/clisqlcmd.php) reference:

--servers=server-id[,...]
Specifies the network address of one or more nodes in the database cluster. By default, sqlcmd attempts to connect to a database on localhost.

Disclosure: I work at VoltDB.

Comment: it means i should provide multiple connection urls to client, will try that

Comment: i tried with [voltdb-client-go]https://github.com/VoltDB/voltdb-client-go with following 

    sql.Open("voltdb", "voltdb://192.168.1.5,voltdb://192.168.1.6")

but it failed to connect to second server (No valid connections failed to login to server voltdb://192.168.1.6)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to connect to a single node try

> jdbc:voltdb://192.168.1.5:`<port>`

as the connection URL or if you wish to connect to cluster try

> jdbc:voltdb://192.168.1.5:`<port>`,192.168.1.6:`<port>`,`<any additional nodes you might have in your cluster>`

as the connection url.